# CSS table-layout: fixed to all columns except the first

Tags: html, css, tablelayout

I am playing with the `table-layout:fixed`, it works almost perfectly for my needs. However, apparently I can not have a column of fixed size that won't change when I add or remove columns dynamically from the table.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/L9rudjng/) is the example. If you add some columns you can see that the first column shrinks and the checkboxes kind of pop out of the columns. How can I make the first column have a fixed size while keeping the `table-layout:fixed` behavior on the other columns?

I am using `table-layout:fixed` because once I add enough columns, it will add a horizontal scroll bar and will guarantee that the columns have at least the width I specified.

Comment: 10px is not enough for the checkboxes. How about measuring how wide the first column should actually be and assigning that width to it. The only reason the column starts out wide enough is that the table is 500px wide, and all columns therefore stretch out to fit. `table-layout:fixed` only works correctly if the sizes match.

Comment: 20px would be ideal but then at the start it would look much wider than 20px and that's what I want to avoid. It should look the same in all situations (either with few columns or with a bunch of columns)

Comment: Then avoid the mismatch between the table being 500px wide and the columns totalling 220px. That is what's causing all the problems.

Comment: @FredericoSchardong - You could recalculate the width whenever you add new table-cells like so [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/0sxw3cw5/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a different approach by not using `table-layout: fixed` and achieve almost the same result. Also, instead of using `width` property for the `<th>`, you can define `min-width`.

Check this updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L9rudjng/5/. I moved the inline CSS into CSS box too.

The table will maintain the 500px until it can't hold enough `<th>`'s with 100px width. Then it will expand and force the horizontal scroll.